# Aurelia non html-only custom element notrendering

Tags: aurelia

I have a simple custom elemen, but it is not rendering.

If i do `<require from="./myfooter.html"></require>` then it renders only the html part. But if i do `<require from="./myfooter"></require>` then nothing is rendered.

What am i doing wrong?

```
    @inject(ConfigService)
export class MyFooterCustomElement{
    private version: string;
    constructor(
        private configService: ConfigService) {
        this.getVersion()
    }



<template>
    <footer class="footer fixed-bottom d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span class="p-2 ml-40">text</span>
        <span class="text-muted d-flex p-2">v${version}</span>
    </footer>
</template>
    async getVersion() {
        this.version = await this.configService.getVersion();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything obiously wrong, please try to reproduce your issue on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zw9zjy0683

Comment: aurelia default rendering is based on naming convention. rename the class from `MyFooterCustomElement` to `MyFooter`, also: when using TS you can write `@autoinject()` instead of `@inject(ConfigService)`.

Comment: also: the template seems to be in the TS file, is this a mistake in your code? or you just posted it wrong here?

Comment: @avramcool jep the naing conventsion was the issue. I read fro maurelia tutorial that aurelia wants the "CustomElement" to the end si i put it there, bit aparently it was false :D. it works now.

Comment: @MarkoTaht Ill put that in an answer, so you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aurelia default rendering is based on naming convention.

rename the class from `MyFooterCustomElemen`t to `MyFooter`

also: when using TS you can write `@autoinject()` instead of `@inject(ConfigService)`.